# Angular2 ng-bootstrap: Reuse modal template with different data

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am building a dashboard-like interface with a set of entities containing comparable data. Each of these entities have an edit-button which I would like to use to open a modal with the respective data displayed.

I would like to reuse the same modal template, and display the data from the entity who's edit-button was clicked. I am using **Angular2** with **ng-bootstrap**, which relies on **Bootstrap 4**.

From the [ng-bootstrap modal docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal), and it's accompanying [plunkr](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/modal/demos/basic/plnkr.html), I was able to create my own working modal component like so (simplified for layout):

```
//editmodal.html

<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  //Modal html content
</template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Edit</button>
```

---

```
//dashboard.html

<template ngbModalContainer></template>
<edit-modal></edit-modal>
```

---

```
//editmodal.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-modal',
  templateUrl: 'entity/assets/templates/editmodal.html'
})

export class EditModal {
  //exported class logic
}
```

The main thing which struck me as odd, coming from the previous bootstrap version, is that the button to open the modal is now displayed within the template itself, encapsulating it. This makes it hard to attach a reference to it so I could figure out what to show from the class logic. How can I achieve this behaviour with Angular2 and ng-bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

You can open a modal window that holds a component from anywhere with the `NgbModal` service.

Call `this.ngbModalService.open(NgbdModalContent)` where `NgbdModalContent` is the component you are going to display in your modal.

Check out Components as content:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Comment: My data is being fetched from the server as a JSON array `[{<entity>},{<entity>}]`, am I supposed to _cast_ each object to a component, and ...? Or is that not the way to go then?

Comment: There is no casting. You can configure the content of your modal by setting the properties of NgbdModalContent. Like NgbdModalContent.name =  entity.name. The value will apear in the {{name}} interpolation of NgbdModalContent's template

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Lev wrote in his answer, you can use the `NgbModal.open()` method and pass it a component to populate the content of a modal.

Now, you don't just want a component. You also want the component to fetch the data from an API. You can do this by combining the `NgbModalRef.componentInstance` parameter, with the `OnInit` interface.

So the solution would be something like this:

```
constructor(
  private modalService: NgbModal
) { }

openModal() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyComponent)
  modalRef.componentInstance.mycomponent_id = 1;
}
```

Your component look like this:

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() mycomponent_id;
  myObject: MyObject;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getObject(mycomponent_id)
      .subscribe(value => this.myObject = value);
  }
  ...
}
```

So basically to summarize it. You open the modal by passing it the component you want as content. Then you set the `mycomponent_id` value from outside your component. **After this** your component will run the `ngOnInit()` method which allow you to use the `mycomponent_id` value to fetch the correct data from your API using your service.