# How to make a Modal reusable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Reusability is very important when programming, and anything we can do to reduce duplication of code is going to help us out.

I have to use Modal popups to display information to users in many places in my Angular 2 project. I am using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) and all of these Modals have the same Header and Footer but body changes in many cases. Sometimes the body just wanted to replace a single place holder, at other times it has some complexity to prepare the dynamic content. And these are triggered or managed by different components.

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) allow us to pass content into a Modal in two ways.

1. as a Template. here wrap the whole Modal html in `<ng-template></ng-template>`
2. as a Component

With the first approach, I have to write the header, body and footer repeatedly per modal.

With the second approach, I can wrap the HTML inside a component but need to put placeholders to make it dynamic. so then I can pass values as follows

```
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
```

But the flexibility is still limited.

### What I am trying to achieve is to make a reusing modal component with Content Projection [Transclusion]

So, in my Common Modal's body looks as below. I placed `<ng-content></ng-content>` as a slot for the Modal's body.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'common-modal',
  template: `
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="common-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{title}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  `,
```

Now I wish I could use it as bellow.

```
<common-modal title="First Modal">
  <span>Welcome Jasnan!</span>
</common-modal>
```

And at some other place

```
<common-modal title="Second Modal">   
     //......
      <tr *ngFor="let student of pagedStudents">
        <td>
          {{student.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{student.grade}}
        </td>
      </tr>
     //......
</common-modal>
```

How can I make this? Is there a way to do this in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)? Thanks for helping me  to figure this out.

Comment: Does my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430342/2335675) answer your question?

Comment: What you have so far looked very good. What issues are seeing with this implementation? Have you tried this?

Comment: Couldn't you use @input values to pass input to your modal ?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this. I am trying to do the same thing. My issue is getting the primary button to work. All the logic is in the modal component, but the buttons are in the base modal component.

Comment: @IanHoar hope the answer below will help you in sometimes in future

Answer (score 5):

The best solution so far is to  create a custom reusable `modal component` and `modal service`  in a shared module (where the component and service is exported), so that it can be used in any other module where shared module is imported

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ModalComponent,
  ],
  providers:[ 
    ModalService
   ],
  exports:[
    ModalComponent
  ]
})
```

**modal.component.html**

```
<div class="custom-modal">
  <div class="model-close-btn">
      <img class="close-image" src="assets/icon/png/close.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from '../services/modal.service';
import { element } from '@angular/core/src/render3';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: string;
  private element: any;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
      this.element = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      let modal = this;

      // ensure id attribute exists
      if (!this.id) {
          console.error('modal must have an id');
          return;
      }

      // move element to bottom of page (just before </body>) so it can be displayed above everything else
      document.body.appendChild(this.element);

      // close modal on background click
      this.element.addEventListener('click', function (e: any) {
          if (e.target.className === 'modal__overlay modal__overlay--toggle') {
              modal.close();
          }
      });

      this.element.addEventListener('click', function (e: any) {
        if (e.target.className === 'model-close-btn' || e.target.className === 'close-image' ) {
            modal.close();
        }
    });

      // add self (this modal instance) to the modal service so it's accessible from controllers
      this.modalService.add(this);
  }

  // remove self from modal service when directive is destroyed
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.modalService.remove(this.id);
      this.element.remove();
  }

  // open modal
  open(): void {
    //console.log(this.element);
      this.element.style.display = 'block';

  }

  // close modal
  close(): void {
      this.element.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**modal.component.scss**

```
/* MODAL STYLES
-------------------------------*/
:host(custom-modal) {
  /* modals are hidden by default */
  display: none;

}

.custom-modal-open {
  /* body overflow is hidden to hide main scrollbar when modal window is open */
  display: block !important;
}

.model-close-btn {
  position: fixed;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;

  img {
    width: 18px;
  }
}
```

**modal.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  private modals: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  add(modal: any) {
    // add modal to array of active modals
    this.modals.push(modal);
  }

  remove(id: string) {
    // remove modal from array of active modals
    this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
  }

  open(id: string) {
    // open modal specified by id
    let modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    modal.open();
  }

  close(id: string) {
    // close modal specified by id
    let modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
    modal.close();
  }

}
```

Now if you want to use this component in a sample component in another module ,  do the following:

Step 1: Import the shared module to the sample module where you want to use the `custom-modal`

**sample.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SampleComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
})
```

Step 2:

**sample.component.ts**

```
  import { ModalService } from 'src/shared/services/modal.service';


  constructor(private modalService: ModalService){}

  //  call this function to open modal by passing modal id
  openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
  }

  // just call this function to close modal by passing modal id
  closeModal(id: string) {
      this.modalService.close(id); 
  }
```

**sample.component.html**

```
<!-- modal popup started -->
  <custom-modal id="custom-modal-one">

   // add your any custom modal template code here and logic in sample.component.ts

  </custom-modal>
<!-- modalp popup ends -->
```

Comment: @Jasnan  just posted answer here so that it may help someone in future. Hope it makes someones life better