# reusable modal with dynamic content in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a reusable modal component I use with several other components.

The modal framework I'm using is from `ng-bootstrap` (`NgbActiveModal`).

The modal just lists a set of strings that come from whichever parent component called it.

However, I want the modal to display differently depending on the parent component. For example, I may need it to display a table instead of a list. I've kludged it this way:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div *ngIf="data.encoding !== undefined">
    <p>Hello {{data.name}}. These are your badly encoded words:</p>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let item of data.words">{{item}}</li></ul>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="data.urls !== undefined">
    <p>Hello {{data.name}}. These are your broken urls:</p>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let item of data.urls">{{item}}</li></ul>
  </div>
```

That works, but it sure is ugly and completely dependent on data items from the parent. What is the angular way to do this correctly?

Comment: The 'angular way' would be to make a component out of this reusable template, and simply inject your component into the parents HTML template whenever necessary. You can have the component take in input , then display it correctly. E.g. if you component is called `app-resuable-component` you can place `<app-reusable-component [data]="mydata"></app-resuable-component>`

Comment: @SyntacticFructose, trying to understand. The template is the 'body' part of my modal component and the two ngIf statements correspond to two different parent components that call the modal. Are you saying I should create a result template component corresponding to each parent component and inject that into the modal component as its body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use input fields I believe. So in modal component something like:

```
Input() content;
```

And then simply:

```
const modal = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
modal.componentInstance.content = 'something here';
```

Add the desired text, or something while opening modal.

Comment: thanks. That is exactly what I've done to get the 'data' into the modal (just json data). I don't know how to add html though, should I write a directive containing the html and add that to the modal as well? I don't understand yet how to add table formatting into the modal for some parent and list formatting for another parent.

Comment: If you want to add html into that, you can use dynamic loading of components - for example create mapings string : component (with your html) and just send string as an input. Then you can easilly load the component into the modal template with all the formatting you need. This is nice explanation of the dynamic loading: https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36.

Comment: if someone looking for a solution then check the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002