# Append component view to body

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

`Angular 7` / `ngx-bootstrap 4.0.1`

`Dependencies` :

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"bootstrap-colorpicker": "2.5.1",
"bootstrap-duallistbox": "3.0.6",
"bootstrap-markdown": "2.10.0",
"bootstrap-progressbar": "0.9.0",
"bootstrap-slider": "9.8.0",
"bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
"bootstrap-timepicker": "0.5.2",
```

In Angular 7, I've a component. It's juste a button and when you click on it, it's show a modal.

If I call it from an element like a div, it's working.

But when I call it from a dropdown, the modal won't appear.

Here is my code :

Normal call : modal is visible :

```
<shared-article-copy (ArticleEM)="addArticle($event, 'articleCopie')" [agentId]="this.samplesBill.recipient.agent_Id"
    *ngIf="this.samplesBill && this.samplesBill.recipient"></shared-article-copy>
```

Call from a dropdown menu : modal is not visible :

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Test 1</button>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Test2 <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li> <shared-article-copy (ArticleEM)="addArticle($event, 'articleCopie')" [agentId]="this.samplesBill.recipient.agent_Id"
            *ngIf="this.samplesBill && this.samplesBill.recipient"></shared-article-copy></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think, the view of my component is bind to the `li` element and not to the body.

here is a part of the code of my component view `shared-article-copy` :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-primary" (click)="loadModalArticleImport()" ng-dblclick="return false;">
    <span class="btn-label">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </span>{{ textTitle }}
</button>

<div bsModal #calculatorModal="bs-modal"  class="modal fade" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: white" [hidden]="!articleCalculator" (onHidden)="closeCalculatorModal()"
>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="background-color: white">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" *ngIf="articleCalculator">
               Modal Header 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               modal body !
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't copy all the code of the component because it's not relevant.

here is a part to :

```
export class SharedArticleCopyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buttonClass: string;
  @Input() agent: Agent; // pour avoir un client par défaut
  @Input() agentId: string; // Quand on a pas lagent mais que son ID people
  @Input() textTitle: string = 'Copier un article existant';
  @Input() calculatorTitle: string = 'Détails de l\'article: ';
  @Input() AgentReadonly: boolean = false;

  @Output() public ArticleEM: EventEmitter<Article> = new EventEmitter<Article>();

  @ViewChild('copyArticleModal') public lgModal: ModalDirective;
  @ViewChild('calculatorModal') public lgCalculatorModal;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private articlesService: ArticlesService, public agentsClientsService: AgentsClientsService, public peopleService: PeopleService,
    private sessionService: SessionService, private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private notificationLGIService: NotificationLGIService, private datePipe: DatePipe, private domService: DomService) {

  }
```

How can I do to make the modal visible even if I call the component from a dropdown menu?

EDIT to add the content of loadModalArticleImport :

```
//lgModal: @ViewChild('copyArticleModal') public lgModal: ModalDirective;
loadModalArticleImport() {      
    this.lgModal.show();
  }
```

Comment: You can shorten safety checks in accessing properties using the `?` operator in templates. For example; `*ngIf="this.samplesBill && this.samplesBill.recipient"` can be shortened to just `*ngIf="this.samplesBill?.recipient"`

Comment: Please update your question to tell us which bootstrap library for Angular that you are using.

Comment: @cgTag I've updated my question. Hope it's what you need.

Comment: @MunimMunna I have edit my question.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproduction on stackblitz

Comment: @Portekoi use the answer from this thread :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002

Comment: you  can just call the function , to invoke the modal ,  this will attach the modal to the body  as you have requested

Answer (score 0):

**You don't see the modal as it is a child of a hidden drop-down menu when it opens.**

When you put the component in a drop-down, you end up with following DOM structure.

```
drop-down menu(position:absolute) > shared-article-copy > modal(position:fixed)
```

When you click the button to open your modal, the modal opens, but the drop-down closes too with display set to `none`.

```
drop-down menu(display:none) > shared-article-copy > modal(position:fixed)
```

So you don't see the drop-down and any of it's children (including your modal).

**Solutions:**

1. Don't put the modal inside a drop-down (Recommended).
2. Patch bootstrap CSS for drop-down containing a modal ([demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-dropdown-containing-modal)).

CSS for bootstrap drop-down that contains a modal:

```css
.dropdown-menu.contains-modal {
    position: unset;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    min-width: unset;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.open>.dropdown-menu.contains-modal {
    position: absolute;
    height: unset;
    width: unset;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: unset;
}
```

And use

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu contains-modal">...
```

instead of

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">...
```